# Converting date using moment giving the day before even time zone provided

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am using moment to convert dates as follows [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-ycvsd4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
  toISO_8601(serverDateFormat: string | Date) {
    moment.locale('en');
    const dateTime =
      serverDateFormat instanceof Date
        ? serverDateFormat
        : new Date(serverDateFormat);

    return moment(dateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
  }
```

and it prints the date as yesterday even though I provided timezone:

> 1988-10-13T23:00:00+02:00

Could you please tell me the right way to convert dates with time zones using moment?

Comment: I got the problem moment considering "Asia/Istanbul" as +2 but it's +3.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a timezone the format can use.

```
toISO_8601(serverDateFormat: string | Date) {
    moment.locale('en');
    const dateTime =
      serverDateFormat instanceof Date
        ? serverDateFormat
        : new Date(serverDateFormat);

    return moment(dateTime)
      .tz('Europe/Volgograd')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
  }
```

For this you need to use `moment-timezone` instead of moment.

See edited stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-9apwsm?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: It shows the same 1988-02-15T23:00:00+02:00. I don't know why it shows me +2 even my country time zone is +3?

Comment: I just saw my stackblitz link didn't get updated. Please check again.

Comment: It worked but you changed the format as I see form +03:00 into 180Z.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right format

```
Wrong : 1988-10-14T00:00:00+03:00
Right : 1988-10-14T00:00:00.180Z
```

This way, the timezone is considered when creating the date.